# Python/Django object.filter(pk__in=variable_list)

Tags: python, django, filter, rawsql

I'm making a raw query where my result of select id from table looks like this:

```
[(517L,), (519L,), (526L,), (537L,), (668L,), (670L,), (671L,), (672L,), (673L,)]
```

I need to use these ids with the __in filter to receive the correct objects here is my code 
**Note** the raw query i've written here is a dummy my real query is complicated and that is why i must use raw query,

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE rule=1)
property_list= cursor.fetchall()
object_list = table1.objects.filter(pk__in=property_list)
```

this results in the following error: `argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a list of tuples, not a 'raw' list of integers, because `fetchall()` returns whole rows, not single columns. Try:

```
pk__in=[p[0] for p in property_list]
```